# export table from one DB and import/merge into another DB with phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a DB1 with a table called 'mytable' and i want to export this with all it's data into DB2 which already has a table called 'mytable'.

So basically merge the data together.  But can seem to do this, if i export and import i always get the following error
Table 'mytable' already exists.

Whats the best way to do this.

Thanks

Ben

Comment: Are these tables stored on one MySQL server or on two different?

Comment: They on my local MAMP instal.

Comment: Then you can use UPDATE, INSERT...SELECT or INSERT...ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE statements.

Comment: Thanks Devart, can these be set when using export in phpmyAdmin as currently when i export the table it's adding in CREATE TABLE to the file

Comment: Ok cool i just removed the creating table stuff from the sql file and started with the Dumping data for table with INSERT INTO.

Answer (score 4):

Using phpmyadmin -

1. DB1 -> goto table -> Export table
2. DB2 -> goto table -> Import Table

Reason:

- Exported sql file contains -

> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `table_name` ( ...

- And

> INSERT INTO table_name ( ...

- Hence, if table already exists,  new rows will simply be inserted into the table.

Comment: For future searchers: In the latest version of phpMyAdmin you need to click the "custom" radio button to open the advanced export settings and then check the `INSERT IGNORE` box and the `IF NOT EXISTS` box. Otherwise when you import you'll get errors (table already exists / row already exists with primary key)